# AngularJS Material not working properly after import

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to import [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/) to my project.I've read how to do it using `bower` and already all needed files are under `bower_components`. I've created simple file to test if everything working properly, but I have a few problems. First of all here is the code:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.9.4/angular-material.min.css">
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">

    <div ng-controller="MyController">

        <md-button class="md-raised" style="background-color: #112233;
               color: white;">Button</md-button>

        <br />
        <md-input-container>
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email">
        </md-input-container>
    </div>


    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-aria.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Angular Material Javascript now available via Google CDN; version 0.9.4 used here -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.9.4/angular-material.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Here you can see what is the output: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avJRZL)
So `md-button` is rendered properly, but the text is not showing, and `md-input-container` is not animating `label` and `input` as you can see from the `CodePen` link. I've used links to libraries from web instead local paths just for showing the result..it's the same.

I am probably missing something small, but these are my first attempts of using `AngularJS` and `Material` so thanks for understanding!

So, what should I do to make the library works as it should be?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One change the controller is not loading up as a result the button is not coming up:

your controller code ***new*** function() is incorrect

```
app.controller("LoginController", new function () {

});
```

corrected controller code

```
app.controller("LoginController", function () {

});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yep, it is working after that change! Thanks for your answer.